# Transifex cannot reset the password

Tags: password-recovery, transifex

When using the [Forgot password?](https://www.transifex.com/user/password/reset/) function on Transifex, I get the following error:

> The user account associated with this email address cannot reset the password.

[image: Transifex cannot reset the password]

This is the email to which notifications go, so I don't know what else to do to reset my password.

Comment: [FAQ](http://docs.transifex.com/faq/) says the same link applies to creating a password when there isn't one, so it's not that.

Comment: This would seem to be something for which you need to contact their support directly.

Comment: @ale Thanks to this question & answer I was able to discover what is happening without waiting for Transifex support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub><sup>Forgot to come and answer myself, so:</sup></sub>

I contacted Transifex directly and it turns out my Transifex account was created via a social media account. In order to make any account changes I would need to either log in via the same social media account, or re-register with the same email address.